# Android SQLite greater than query isn't working how I expect it to

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Okay so I'm clearly missing something very fundamental here but I can't figure out what it is.

the problem:

I'm writing a unit test for a database query where I search for all shifts that have happened **AFTER** a certain date (the dates which I'm storing in epoch milliseconds) so logic dictates that I construct a query where the shift start dates are **GREATER THAN** some specified date, which seems simple enough yet my test is failing, and weirdly when I flip my greater than to a lesser than the test passes o_O.

this is my query:

```
public Cursor getAutoClockedShifts(Long dateSince) {
    String sortOrder = COL_START_DATE + " DESC";
    String selection = COL_ADDED_MANUALLY + " = " + "?" + " AND " + COL_START_DATE + " > " + "?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {"0", dateSince.toString()};
    cursor = database.query(false, getTableName(), null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

this is the fake data that I'm using for the unit test:

```
private HashMap<String, ?> createShiftHashMap(){
    HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put(ShiftDb.COL_ADDED_MANUALLY, 0);
    values.put(ShiftDb.COL_START_DATE, 1478871347000L);//HUMAN READABLE = 11/11/2016, 13:35:47
    return values;

}
```

and finally this is the unit test I've put together:

```
    @Test
public void tesGetAutomaticallyAddedShifts() throws Exception {
    long result = shiftDb.create(createShiftHashMap());
    Cursor c = shiftDb.get(result);

    assertEquals(1478871347000L, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ShiftDb.COL_START_DATE)));
    assertTrue(1478871347000L > 1447421747000L);
    assertTrue(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ShiftDb.COL_START_DATE)) > 1447421747000L);

    Cursor c1 = shiftDb.getAutoClockedShifts(1447421747000L);//HUMAN READABLE = 13/11/2015, 13:35:47
    assertNotEquals(0, c1.getCount());
}
```

I made sure that my data was what I thought it was by commenting out the last two lines and verifying that the first 3 asserts pass (which they do) but the last assert keeps on failing with this message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Values should be different. Actual: 0
```

I know it can't be the case that Android/Java/SQLite is making a maths mistake, but I'm at a loss for whats wrong here, As I mentioned above this test passes if I flip the greater than to lesser than but that makes no sense as the start date value is definitely greater than the specified date.

Please help.

Comment: Are these values supposed to be numbers or strings? That code appears to use both types ...

Comment: they're suppose to be numbers, by my understanding a query should be fine if you use strings

Comment: No, numbers and strings never match (unless the column affinity forces a conversion).